# What is wrong with my rewrite rule to exclude directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Root directory like this:

```
/index.php
/App
/Extend
/PHPrpc
...
```

I want exclude sub directory `/Extend` and `/Phprpc` from the rules.

The old .htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

The following is modified by me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(Extend|PHPrpc) - [L]  #exclude directory
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

But I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Any advise?

Comment: Nilesh has an answer. With your current rules you create infinite rewrite loop hence the 500 error. If you check your Apache error log you will see an entry with this kind of text: _"Maximum number of rewrite iterations reached.."_

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude the URLs, simply filter it using RewriteCond:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Extend|Phprpc)/`

Comment: +1 To make 100% sure that it will exclude directory and not a file with such name, add slash `/` at the end of your line.